# How do I exit Notepad++ via ESC?

Tags: notepad++

It used to work as I remember but now it has stopped working.

Is there a setting I cannot find? (not even via Google)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to Settings > Shortcut Mapper > then go to line 19 which is Exit. You can set ESC key as exit.

Comment: ah. I missed it. ticked.